# Missing "menu" in the "res" file

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm learning now the Java language and using Eclipse for that. When I create an "Android application project" I find out that the **menu** folder is **missing** in the res folder. Moreover, in the MainActivity.java I get the error "The import android.view.MenuItem is never used" beside the import android.view.MenuItem.

So, if someone knows how to fix it then please post a solution.

Comment: These two are not related but they indicate you don't have a valid Eclipse Android project. I suggest to go back an do your Eclipse and  Android setup _exactly_ like the tutorial says. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I reinstalled the whole program with the packages 3 times and followed each step, but still get that problem. So what could I do?

Comment: just create a menu folder already...on the res folder "right click" and go to new..choose "new folder" and then name it menu..

Comment: That would be an option, however I still get that error message.

Comment: @Basem there is no way to know what you did wrong :). Clear everything, start from the beginning and follow each step the tutorial says.

Comment: what type of project are you creating? Maybe some kind of project don't include folder menu.

Comment: @Mike its a "Android application project". Each time I create a new project I get that error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I create an "Android application project" I find out that the menu folder is missing in the res folder

If you want this folder, create it. There are millions of possible resource folders; the Eclipse wizards will not create them all.

> Moreover, in the MainActivity.java I get the error "The import android.view.MenuItem is never used" beside the import android.view.MenuItem.

That is no an error. It is a warning, indicating that the code has an import that is not needed. If you are not planning on using that import any time soon, delete that line.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, how is it possible that in the tutorial the "menu" folder is located in the resources and by me it is missing? I did all steps 3 times again.

Comment: @Basem: First, I have no idea what tutorial you are referring to. Second, the tools changed a fair bit in the past two weeks, and the documentation frequently lags behind.

Comment: It's a tutorial from Lin**.com which explains each steps great, therefore it couldn't be a mistake by them. So eclipse might have changed through the updates?

Comment: @Basem: The behavior of the ADT plugin for Eclipse has changed a fair bit so far in 2013. Moreover, what determines the folders that are created and the lines of code in the generated files are templates, and those templates are easy for Google to change. Any tutorial that relies upon those templates being consistent will be frequently out of date. I wound up changing the tutorials in my book to have you import a starter project, rather than use the wizards, for just this reason.

Comment: I see. Of course, I won't change the course for that point and I have read on other pages that their are frequently changes in the structure. Thanks for your help.